# Crear un TRIGGER en el que al modificar los valores booleanos de una columna, inserte la fecha actual en otra columna de la misma tabla

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, mysql-workbench, trigger

Estoy creando una base de datos sobre información de tiendas de aplicaciones y bueno, me quería aventurar a crear mi primer trigger, pero algo en mi sintaxis falla (soy nuevo programando).

Os pongo en contexto: He creado 2 tablas, Empleados y Empresas, con relacion N:N, esto ha creado otra tabla de la relacion entre estas entidades que es TRABAJAN, ahí he metido la Fecha de inicio en la empresa y la Fecha de fin y además, he puesto otra columna con valores booleanos sobre si están trabajando o no. Cuando inserté los datos permiti que si seguian trabajando, tuviesen un valor NULL.

Bien, lo que quiero es crear un trigger que al modificar el estado de la columna trabajando de 1 a 0, me modifique el valor NULL de la columna Fecha_fin por el valor de la fecha actual del sistema.

Os dejo el código y el intento de trigger que hice:

```
CREATE DATABASE Info_Tiendas_App2;
USE Info_Tiendas_App2;

CREATE TABLE Empleados (
codEmpleado SMALLINT PRIMARY KEY,
DNI VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
NomEmpleado VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
Calle VARCHAR(30),
Numero NUMERIC(3,0),
CodPostal NUMERIC(5,0),
CorreoElect VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE Empresas (
codEmpresa SMALLINT PRIMARY KEY,
NomEmpresa VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
PaisFacturacion VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
AnnoCreacion NUMERIC(4,0),
Correo VARCHAR(50),
PagWeb VARCHAR(40)
);

CREATE TABLE TRABAJAN (
codEmpleado SMALLINT,
codEmpresa SMALLINT,
Fecha_inicio DATE,
Fecha_fin DATE,
Trabajando BOOLEAN,
PRIMARY KEY (codEmpleado, codEmpresa), 
FOREIGN KEY (codEmpleado) REFERENCES Empleados(codEmpleado)
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (codEmpresa) REFERENCES Empresas(codEmpresa)
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE 
);

-- Aquí el trigger
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER TRABAJAN_AI 
AFTER UPDATE ON Trabajando
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE Trabajando SET CURDATE -- Esto es por que quiero que cuando actualice el valor  1, me ponga la fecha actual del sistema.
WHERE OLD.Trabajando = 1;
END;$$
```

Aprendería muchísimo si me ayudáis a resolver este trigger, agradezco vuestra ayuda de antemano. Un saludo

Comment: No soy muy bueno con ```SQL``` pero, noto cosas que no deberían ser como que usas ```values``` en vez de ```set``` que es no propio del update. O que no usas el where lo que podría modificar todas las filas